# Fields missing in CRM RetrieveMultiple method via query expression

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

It seems like I have come across another one of those gotcha's sending me on yet another learning curve. I'm working with MS Dynamics CRM 2016 on premise and trying to return the attribute and value for "plugintypeidname" from the entity "SdkMessageProcessingStep". This has opened up a can of worms in terms of the gaps in my knowledge and was hoping for some kind of explanation.

---

### ***System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1: 'Cannot specify child attributes in the columnset for Retrieve. Attribute: plugintypeidname'***

---

### System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1: 'Retrieve can only return columns that are valid for read.  Column : supportingsolutionid. Entity : sdkmessageprocessingstep'

If I take a peek at the view behind that system entity in MSCRM I can see inline comments, none of the logical attributes are available but most but not all of the physical attributes are available within my query columnset (query expression).

I know  about columns missing when the value is NULL and you should check via Entity.Contains(someKey) this however isn't the issue. As that value is 100% populated.

Why are they not available and is there somewhere I can read about this behavior and the difference between a Logical attribute vs. physical attribute? It also is a problem if I ever needed that field value where CRM seemingly doesn't always return the column desired from the DB?

**My Query**

```
>    select 
>      sdkmessageprocessingstepsecureconfigid --always null
>      ,versionnumber  -- populated values and yet missing?
>      ,eventhandlertypecode -- populated values and yet missing?
>      ,overwritetime -- -- populated values and yet missing?
>      ,supportingsolutionid -- -- populated values and yet missing?
>       from SdkMessageProcessingStep
>        where
>          StateCode=0 AND
>          StatusCode=1 
>          and
>          CreatedByName='System'
```

**Missing Fields**

```
>  [ImpersonatingUserIdName], -- logical field so never available
>     [CreatedOnBehalfByName], -- logical field so never available
>     [CreatedByName], -- logical field so never available
>     [ModifiedByName], -- logical field so never available
>     [ModifiedOnBehalfByYomiName], -- logical field so never available
>     [ModifiedOnBehalfByName], -- logical field so never available
>     [CreatedOnBehalfByYomiName], -- logical field so never available
>     [SdkMessageIdName], -- logical field so never available
>     [PluginTypeIdName], -- logical field so never available
>     EventHandlerName, -- logical field so never available
>     sdkmessageprocessingstepsecureconfigId --always null    ,versionnumber  -- populated values and yet missing?   
> ,eventhandlertypecode -- populated values and yet missing?   
> ,overwritetime -- -- populated values and yet missing?   
> ,supportingsolutionid -- -- populated values and yet missing?
```

**Query Expression**

```
 CrmServiceClient _crmClient = new CrmServiceClient(targetConnection);
QueryExpression query =
            new QueryExpression
            {
                EntityName = "sdkmessageprocessingstep",
                ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("name", "sdkmessageprocessingstepid", "description", "eventhandlertypecode",
                "sdkmessageprocessingstepsecureconfigid",
                "versionnumber",
                "eventhandlertypecode",
                "overwritetime",
                "supportingsolutionid",
                "plugintypeidname"
                )

            };

 filterAnd = new FilterExpression
            {
                FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
                Conditions = {
                    new ConditionExpression("statecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 0),
                    new ConditionExpression("statuscode", ConditionOperator.Equal, 1),
                    new ConditionExpression("createdbyname", ConditionOperator.Equal, "System");
                }
            };

query.Criteria.AddFilter(filterAnd);
EntityCollection rs = _crmClient.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if there is a specific "definition" provided by MS, but those fields are mostly the label representations of the underlying ids themselves, or system fields which, in the vast majority of cases, should not be available for querying. For example, ModifiedByName has an underlying ModifiedBy, which is the GUID of the user/team which modified the record last. The logical names also represent what's displayed to the user in the UI (since that can be changed in many cases) as opposed to the actual column name in the db.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. I was just surprised that fields in the underlying views were not available to query but I accept your points around system fields etc. However, it's interesting that two of those fields actually cause an exception in CRM on the RetrieveMultiple method and the others didn't? Namely PluginTypeIdName and SupportingSolutionId

Comment: I am not sure! Haven't come across that before.

Comment: Can you post actuall query featuring IOrganizationService ?

Comment: I'm great at finding errors even when its not intentional! does my head in. I have updated question to include the query expression per Ondrej request

Comment: Also I don't know if this would matter but I am calling the execute method on the main CrmServiceClient type rather than casting my object to a Proxy (i.e. OrganizationWebProxyClient or OrganizationServiceProxy) simply because I have more methods available to me by using the base class.

Comment: I have a very similar problem. EF will see all the fields of Dynamics entity, but will only fetch some. For instance, if I'm doing a clean Frist() then I get most of the values. However, I noticed that some values are missing and even when using Include it won't fetch them. Running the same query in LinqPad fetches those values. Loss of values is even greater after join. Any idea how to solve this?